# How to use dynamic-library-alist to load my own DLL?

Tags: microsoft-windows

I found Emacs has a [dynamic-library-alist](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dynamic-Libraries.html#Dynamic-Libraries). But there's no instruction about how to use the libraries after it is been loaded...any idea?

What I want to acheive is to load a DLL on my Windows system and call the exposed function.

Comment: This variable is intended to be used for checking what libraries are present, not to load new ones...

Comment: So dynamic-library-alist won't work.  Any suggestions on how to accomplish what the OP wants to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting @wasamasa's comment to a answer:

`dynamic-library-alist` has nothing to do with loading DLL on Windows platform.

Quoting its docstring:

> Also note that this is not a generic facility for accessing external
>   libraries; only those already known by Emacs will be loaded.

Comment: Beside writing the answer you should also accept it to mark this question as solved.